# CSS media queries not working for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

This is the following media query I am using:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) { // CSS }
```

This is what my webpage looks like on a desktop, width > 800px

[image: Image 1]

on a desktop, width < 800px

[image: enter code here]

So, that all works. but on a mobile phone, the media query doesn't activate, it displays the standard desktop view (image 1). It's a high end smartphone, which I assume is > 800px. So what can I do? Are there any media queries to target smartphones, or any Javascript (jQuery) plugins?

Comment: Do you have the mobile meta tag included ?

Comment: What device is it? What browser is it running? Also, try putting this in your head tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: If the mobile device has a viewport width of more than 800px, how is it not working then?

Comment: What device is it? not all latest devices has width>800. try to rotate the screen

Comment: thanks guys. that simple hehehe. appreciate it. its an motorola XT925

Comment: your title is wrong then, should be: `css media queries work as expected`  see @Stijn 's comment

Comment: This question should be closed because there is no problem to resolve (working as expected).